# How to generate specific data pattern used for data mining in python?

Tags: python, dataset, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I need to create dataset that has specific shape like in the picture.

[image]

How can I do this in Python ?

Comment: Use the source, Luke.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html

The `sklearn` package includes a `datasets` sub-module with dataset-generators for each pattern - `make_circles`, `make_moons`, `make_blobs`.